# Notebook pauses when battery is inserted

Tags: laptop, freeze, battery, hp-elitebook

I have an HP Elitebook 2530p that is experiencing some odd behaviour.

Symptoms:

- Booting with battery causes blank screen
- Booting without battery works like normal
- Inserting battery while powered on causes the computer to freeze
- Removing battery while frozen returns it to normal, but the clock
  resumes from when the battery was inserted.

What causes this? Is there anything one can do to fix it?

Comment: I wouldn't remove/insert a battery whilst the laptop is running if I were you. Regarding the freezing issue, is it an original battery or a third-party replacement?

Comment: What is the OS? That could be a culprit of the freezing.

Comment: @James if I didn't I wouldn't be able to diagnose the problem? But still it hasn't given me a solution... What could go wrong?

Comment: @Sion Windows 7. But it's more of a pause, removing the battery causes it to resume normal operation again. But the OS is certainly not the culprit here as it does the same when no OS has been loaded.